# Structuring Python project to allow scripts to import local packages, referencing relative to the project root directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, directory, path

I have a python project set up where my scripts are stored in one folder, my packages and data in other folders, and I am trying to organize the best structure and procedures for making referencing between these items more robust:

```
project_dir/
    data/
        raw/
            source_1.csv
            source_2.csv
        processed/
            tidydata.csv
            results.csv
    src/
        scripts/
            clean_raw_data.py
            calc_results.py
        packages/
            import_tools
                tool_a.py
                tool_b.py
            calc_tools
    Makefile
```

My desire is to be able to robustly reference my packages through imports (`./src/packages`) and my data (`./data`)
with file read and write operations from any of my scripts in the `./src/scripts` folder.

My current setup involves doing things like this:

To import packages (this seems like bad practice to call functions in order to import other functions):

```
# clean_raw_data.py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent))
import packages.import_tools as imptool
```

To read and write files:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('../../data/raw/source_1.csv')
# operations
df.to_csv('../../data/processed/tidydata.csv')
```

Ideally I would prefer that everything were available referenced from the project folder `project_dir`
in any file or script in my structure, such that I could do things like:

```
import src.packages.import_tools as imptool
```

```
df = pd.read_csv(f'{ROOT_DIR}/data/raw/source_1.csv')
```

In some way or another. I presume there is a best practice guideline for configuring things to behave
in a similar way but haven't seen any good recommendations. What would be the best approach
for handling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python the mechanisms to reference data files and source code are completely different. While you always have to specify the full path to your data file when you want to open it, Python will use the **sys.path** to autonomously search for modules that you want to import. However, "hacking" the sys.path manually in all your script files is bad practice. Instead, use **pip** to install your project in [editable](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) mode:

```
pip install --editable path/to/project_dir
```

but make sure there is a minimal *setup.py* in *project_dir* with the following contents

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='myproject')
```

pip will put the symlink *myproject.egg-info* into your *site-packages* folder that you can verify that via

```
pip show myproject
```

This allows you to import your packages using what is called *absolute imports* by always starting from within your project_dir

```
from src.packages.import_tools import tool_a
```

(Note that your `import packages.import_tools as imptool` didn't work anyway since *import_tools* is a package and not a module.)

The next things you could add to your *project_dir* are a *README.MD*, a *requirements.txt* and a *test* folder for your unit tests. And keep in mind that the distinction between *scripts* and *packages* is somewhat artificial, because all Python files are basically modules that can be imported.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I haven't seen the --editable option before. I'm surprised this use case is not more commonly described anywhere. I've had a heck of a time finding a balance between "just put all your functions and calls into some script" and "here's how to setup a package ready for production". Not much in between, I've found. What happens if you don't use "--editable" btw?